# Code for using Wired USB Scanner in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: java, xamarin.forms, jar, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to write the code for using the wired usb scanner on Android devices. I tried the ZXing for using camera but it's too slow.

I tried the library for Java and it works perfectly on Java. Right now, I want to use that library to build the app on Xamarin.Forms by using the Binding Library. But I'm not familiar with Xamarin.Forms, so is there any tutorial to help me convert my code to Xamarin.Form?

In Java, I used these following code to use the library. I also attached entire MainActivity and Jar file. Thanks in advance.

Main Activity
https://ufile.io/2t83bb1d

Jar File
https://ufile.io/b0xqifpc

```
private static final int HIDE_SERIAL_CTL_MSG = 1;
private static final int DEVICE_POWER_STATE_CHANGE_MSG = 2;
private static final int CLEAR_RESULT_MSG = 4;
private static String TAG = "ACT_QRScan";
USBQRscanFactory usbScan;
private Button btnLightSetting,
        btnScan, btnContinuoutStart, btnPowerOnOff,
        btnSetTimeOut;
private EditText etTimeOutSeconds;
private TextView mShow;
private TextView mTvstatus;
private ScanBroadcastReceiver scanBroadcastReceiver;
private boolean mWorkingStateFlag = false;
private boolean mPowerStateFlag = true;
private Context mCtx;
private Player mPlayer;



 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

if (null == mPlayer)
            mPlayer = new Player();
        mPlayer.init(mCtx, R.raw.done);
        scanBroadcastReceiver = new ScanBroadcastReceiver(mPlayer, R.raw.done);

    hideSerialCtls(true);

    usbScan = USBQRscanFactory.createInstance();
  private Intent getUSBScanService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction("com.unistrong.qrcode.USBScanService");
    i.setPackage(getApplication().getPackageName());
    return i;
}


private void openScanner(boolean open) {
    if (open == mWorkingStateFlag) return;
    if (open) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
            usbScan.open();
            usbScan.enableAddKeyValue(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        if (null != usbScan) {
            if (btnContinuoutStart.getTag().equals("1")) {
                usbScan.continuousScan(false);
                btnContinuoutStart.setTag("0");
                btnContinuoutStart.setText(getString(R.string.str_continuous_scan_start));
            }
            usbScan.close();
        }
        H.sendEmptyMessage(CLEAR_RESULT_MSG);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to create an Android binding library to use the JAR library from Xamarin Android.  Then you can use a DependencyService or custom renderer to expose the Xamarin Android implementation in Forms

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, I created Android binding but could not find a way to use those class in the jar probably in Xamarin.Form. Is there any tutorial for this?
Thanks,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/